# Reinitialize Javascript after AJAX refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, video-player, facetwp

We are using the Easy Video Player in on a WordPress website in combination with FacetWP. This is software we use to filter. This filter is working with AJAX and there is no page refresh after an interaction with the filter, it is done with AJAX.

This is causing problems with the Video player we are using. We think some Javascript is not loaded because of the AJAX refresh with the filter.

We allready know this from FacetWP in order to reinitialize Javascript after interaction with the filter:

[facetwp-loaded Event](https://facetwp.com/help-center/developers/javascript-reference/facetwp-loaded/)

We also found the PHP script that enqueue the CSS and JS files.

```
function easy_video_player_enqueue_scripts() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        $plugin_url = plugins_url('', __FILE__);
        $enable_jquery = get_option('evp_enable_jquery');
        if ($enable_jquery) {
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        }
        //wp_register_style('plyr-css', 'https://cdn.plyr.io/3.6.7/plyr.css');
        wp_register_style('plyr-css', $plugin_url . '/lib/plyr.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('plyr-css');
        //wp_register_script('plyr-js', 'https://cdn.plyr.io/3.6.7/plyr.js');
        wp_register_script('plyr-js', $plugin_url . '/lib/plyr.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('plyr-js');
    }
}
```

But to be very honest, I can't figure out what I have to load in the FacetWP function in order to re-run the JS to get the player working with filtering.

Anyone can help me a step furder in order to fix this?

**EDIT**

Got it to work with the help of John:)

```
const player = Plyr.setup('video', { ratio: '16:9', });
```

Complete code looks like this:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('facetwp-loaded', function() {
    const player = Plyr.setup('video', { ratio: '16:9', });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s just a wild guess by looking into the [videoplayersource](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr#initialising) and combine with the facetwp-loaded event.

maybe it works when you add this handler to the bottom of your page (not the content loaded with ajax):

```
document.addEventListener('facetwp-loaded', function() {
      const players = Plyr.setup('video');
});
```

if you are getting $ is not defined, try replace $ with jQuery

PS: i just realize that your version of easy-video-player differs from the link i posted above, maybe you should upgrade it to the latest version so it uses flowplayer like in this answer

Comment: Hello john, thank you very much for the answer but the version in the github is 8 years old and I am using the latest version that is on WordPress and that is not using flowplayer any more so the answer you suggested is not working unfortunately. @john Smith, just found the Github of the player they are using now, maybe there is something I can you there. https://github.com/sampotts/plyr

Comment: oh okay, so i updated the answer and replaced the link to target the `initialization` section. Maybe you have to play around with the selector, but in general you want to "reinitialize" on facetwp-loaded event

Comment: Thank you again for helping me @john Smith, apreciate it:) I just tried the code you suggested but no luck. You are still refering to "if (typeof $.fn.flowplayer == 'function') {" flowplayer, should'nt that be different?

Comment: const players = Plyr.setup('video'); This is working and loading the player but way to big so I think I have to pass some other values too

Comment: you might have to lookup where the options are stored or with which options the inital player gets initialized and store them i.e in a js-variable. But thats up to you as i have no access to your project ;) hope i led u into the correct direction

Comment: I found the default options of the player but since I am a bit new to Javascript I have trouble on how to get those options in the current function or on how to trigger them. https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/blob/master/src/js/config/defaults.js, Maybe you can me help one last time with the options?:) Loading the default player I did not changes any setting so default settings are fine for me but seems with only using "const players = Plyr.setup('video');" no options are set

Comment: hmn .. the default options are probably used when you dont pass any options (like you do right now). What you have to look for are the options that the wp-plugin generates out of your configuration, maybe look into the source-code and look for "Plyr" initialisations, can you post a link to the source of the exact wp-plugin you use?

Comment: I though so too so something isn't loading and I don't know what. This is the exact wp-plugin I use: https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-video-player/

Comment: i found the generated script tag: https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/easy-video-player/trunk/easy-video-player.php#L297

Comment: Aaah that is what we need. But we need those PHP variables that are used in the script too, right? I took a look at the script and is it possible to only use this: With no video_id but just "plyr"? const evplayer{$video_id} = new Plyr(document.getElementById('$video_id'));

Comment: I can't get it to work. const players = Plyr.setup('video');, this is the closest I get in order to load the player but this is not the best solution I think. The URL with script you provided is what we need (I think) but this is in full PHP with Javascript in it and I don't know what to use or change to get it to work properly:(

Comment: i´m sorry i dont really see another solution that editing or patching the source, so that you set those php values to javascript variables you can then later access :/

Comment: I got it working. With the default options it was still missing some class with the AJAX filter being used. I now set it up like this. See my original question and Edit part.

Comment: nice man :-) glad it works